# Rails print user input and tag at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sanitization

I would like to print with <%= %>. PS: the following works but looks bad.

```
<%= "String: #{html_escape @user.input} <br>".html_safe unless @user.input.blank? %>
```

I know I can do

```
<% unless @user.input.blank? %>
  String: <%= @user.input %><br>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to write a method that looks like that:

```
def print_if_not_blank (string, input)
  string.insert(html_escape input).html_safe unless  input.blank?
end

printf_if_not_blank "String: #{} <br>", @user.input
```

I guess I could always have a param like "String: EVIL < br>" and than replace "EVIL" but that's not better than my current solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a helper like this:

```
def print_if_present(template, input)
  return unless input.present?

  string = template % { input: html_escape(input) }
  string.html_safe
end
```

What is used like this in your view:

```
<%= print_if_present('String: #{input} <br>', @user.input)
```

Comment: I had the exact same idea, except I added an exception if the #{input} is missing. But other than that my solution looks the same. I hoped there's a better solution. I'll wait for more solutions but thank you for your answer!